ros noetic installation on ubuntu server 20.04
ros noetic installation on ubuntu server 20.04
sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports InRelease
Hit:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security InRelease
Get:5 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Reading package lists... Done      
E: Release file for http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/focal-updates/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 6h 8min 0s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
rpi@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt install ros-noetic-desktop-full
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-noetic-desktop-full


Check your system clock PLUS timezone... Your system clock is 6 hours out (or timezone is set to something six hours different probably to your actual timezone)

Does this answer your question? Getting 'Release is not valid yet' while updating ubuntu docker container
